# How to console.log the imagerySet of a layer?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I found this simple openlayers example online , the map initialization looks like below:

```
var styles = [
  'Road',
  'Aerial',
  'AerialWithLabels',
  'collinsBart',
  'ordnanceSurvey'
];
var layers = [];
var i, ii;
for (i = 0, ii = styles.length; i < ii; ++i) {
  layers.push(new ol.layer.Tile({
    visible: false,
    preload: Infinity,
    source: new ol.source.BingMaps({
      key: 'Ak-dzM4wZjSqTlzveKz5u0d4IQ4bRzVI309GxmkgSVr1ewS6iPSrOvOKhA-CJlm3',
      imagerySet: styles[i]
      // use maxZoom 19 to see stretched tiles instead of the BingMaps
      // "no photos at this zoom level" tiles
      // maxZoom: 19
    })
  }));
}
var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: layers,
  // Improve user experience by loading tiles while dragging/zooming. Will make
  // zooming choppy on mobile or slow devices.
  loadTilesWhileInteracting: true,
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [-6655.5402445057125, 6709968.258934638],
    extent: [-16655.5402445057125, 6609968.258934638,0,6809968],
    maxZoom: 20, 
    minZoom:13,
    zoom: 13
  })
});

var select = document.getElementById('layer-select');
function onChange() {
  var style = select.value;
  for (var i = 0, ii = layers.length; i < ii; ++i) {

    console.log( layers[i].getSource().item(1) +  " " + styles[i] );

    layers[i].setVisible(styles[i] === style);
  }
}

select.addEventListener('change', onChange);
onChange();
```

Now what i really was trying to do was , i wanted to console.log the `imagerySet` of every layer , inside the below peice of code:

```
function onChange() {
  var style = select.value;
  for (var i = 0, ii = layers.length; i < ii; ++i) {

    console.log( layers[i].getSource().item(1) +  " " + styles[i] );

    layers[i].setVisible(styles[i] === style);
  }
}
```

I tried the below few method:

```
layers[i].getSource().item(1);
```

and

```
layers[i].getSource().getImagerySet();
```

but it does't give me the desired result , can anybody corrent me and tell me whats the correct way to `imagerySet` inside the loop ?

**[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/o6wre0d3/)**

Answer (score 2):

`imagerySet` is a specific attribute for bing maps. It wont work in any other tile type. `getImagerySet` wont work as there is no such function documented on ol3. Also seems that ol3 have no function to retrieve the bing image type.
You can always pass a custom attribute during layer initilasation and the retrive it using the `get` method.
Check the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/gu7omhnf/) I use `myattribute` on layer and pass the `styles[i]` value. Then I can get this value using `layers[i].get('myattribute')`